# Choosing correct numpy or pandas data structure

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a function that generates square ndarrays of [ex. shape (10,10)]. The values are floats.

I need to be able to say, "tell me the standard deviation of an arbitrary cell [ex. (3,6)] in all of the 10x10 ndarrays I just generated"

I don't know what the best structure to store these 10x10 ndarrays is.  I was searching through older StackOverflow questions and people were warning against making "arrays of arrays" for example.

I'd like something that is efficient, but also easily manipulated (being able to do descriptive statistics on slices of the three dimensional structure).

Not sure how to assemble this, and whether I should be making it a dataFrame (which the original data that I have been processing was in) or a numpy array, or something else.

Wisdom please?

Comment: Or a multidimensional array?

Comment: A 3 dimensional array `(10, 10, n)` seems appropriate

Answer (score 0):

A pandas [Panel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel) seems to fit your requirements nicely. An example of creating the data structure you describe (with n=15, filled with random numbers) and extracting the standard deviation for each data point in the 10x10 square across all squares is:

```
import pandas
import numpy
wp = pandas.Panel(numpy.random.randn(15, 10, 10))
wp.std(axis=0)
```